# How to add transparency and radial gradient to a vector?

Tags: vector, transparency, gradient

In a way to meet the Shutterstock guidelines I need to convert my Illustraton ai vector files to EPS 10 format. This conversion can create rasterised elements in an EPS10 files. Shutterstock does not accept vector files which contain raster elements, so the question is -

How can I successfully add transparency or radial gradient to a vector without causing it to rasterize the effect, what is the best way to add these effects? I've been looking for answer for this problem forever, I watch everyday tutorials of artists creating vectors using multiply masks and overlay, screen, transparency and raise a big question mark in my mind.

ADD: I know this link https://www.shutterstock.com/contributorsupport/articles/en_US/kbat02/Best-Practice-Recommendations-for-Saving-EPS-Files?l=en_US&c=ContributorKB%3AGuidelines_by_content_type&fs=Search&pn=1 and doing as it says doesn't work.

Comment: The link I've seen and read multiple times, it doesn't answer my doubt, I've done as in their tutorial and image was still rejected.

Comment: Many of us understand complex underhood things if they can see them. Maybe you can make one simple non-acceptable Ai file for them to see. But use a cloud which doesn't start by demanding email address or login.

Comment: In general, an AI 10 EPS **will** support a gradient with transparency *without* rasterizing - radial or otherwise. The AI10 EPS format actually creates an *opacity mask* and an underlayment for such elements (all vector). So... without more detail, it's difficult to provide any help. (Note **blending modes** are another matter entirely - perhaps *that* is your problem?)

Comment: Their support contacted me to tell there are alternatives to gradient and these masks I searched and break my mind to find how to imitate transparency, gradient effect, without success, and how to add multiply and overlay too without resulting in a rejected bitmap, is that possible at all? See all I want to know is how to create transparency effects in my arts, to look polished and professional, I believe it needs this touch, I could discard it but I prefer transparency in my works, but when the intention is to create a vector and not just a jpg or png so it seems to be a mission impossible.